# Transfer Attributes from One Geo-Node to Another

Tags: geometry-nodes

**TL;DR How do I transfer attributes from one geo node on one `Object` to another geo node on another `Object`?**

[image]

Hey guys, trying to write an attribute in a node tree that is used on one geometry node modifier on one `Object` and then read that attribute in a different node tree used in a different geometry node modifier on a different `Object` so that one `Object` can act as a data source for multiple other `Object`s.

The way I'm trying to do this right now is according to the below diagram. The problem I'm having is demonstrated through the red lassoing in that I am expecting to be seeing `(1,1,1)` for my `Sample Index` node `out` field, but I am rather seeing `(0,0,0)`:
[image: A diagram walking through how I want to transfer an attribute from one Object to another.]

I don't understand enough about Geometry Nodes to know why the above doesn't work, but learning from previous questions I've posed to this website I'm this time going to include a `.blend` file for those more knowledgable to explore right away which those interested can find at the top of the post.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: In "PostModifierScaling_Source" graph, try to add a "Geometry to Instance" node between "Group Input" and the first "Store Named Attribute" (the one with "postModifierScaling_factor") nodes. The issue seems to be that you store attributes in "Instance" domain, but you have no instance (check in the Spreadsheet Viewer...).

Comment: @StefLAncien My tree still isn't working BUT that did resolve the crux of this post in that I'm now getting `(1,1,1)` when reading the relevant attribute, so clearly something else is wrong that I'll have to look into. TYVM!

Answer (score 0):

To quote user StefAncien,

> In "PostModifierScaling_Source" graph, try to add a "Geometry to Instance" node between "Group Input" and the first "Store Named Attribute" (the one with "postModifierScaling_factor") nodes. The issue seems to be that you store attributes in "Instance" domain, but you have no instance (check in the Spreadsheet Viewer...).

Doing as such resolved the issue my question posed, although my specific tree still isn't working, but that's for my own investigation from here.